# ActiveRecord::UnknownAttributeError on User.advertisements.create

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord, has-many

I have a rails application that user users and sessions. Users have many advertisements, and, while changing the user model to have many advertisements, I run into an Unknown Attribute Error.

Advertisements_controller.rb

```
class AdvertisementsController < ApplicationController
  before_action :require_user, only: [:new, :create]

  def index
    @advertisements = Advertisement.all
  end
  def new
    @advertisement = Advertisement.new
  end
  def create
    @advertisement = current_user.advertisements.create(advertisement_params)
    if @advertisement.save
      redirect_to '/advertisements/index'
    else
      redirect_to '/advertisements/new'
    end
  end

  private

    def advertisement_params
      params.require(:advertisement).permit(:title, :body)
    end
end
```

user_controller.rb

```
class UsersController < ApplicationController

  def new
     @user = User.new
  end

  def create
    @user = User.new(user_params)
    if @user.save then
      session[:user_id] = @user.id
      redirect_to '/'
    else
      redirect_to '/signup'
    end
  end

  private

    def user_params
      params.require(:user).permit(:first_name, :last_name, :email, :password)
    end
end
```

user.rb

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :advertisements, dependent: :destroy

  # Rails's built-in password security
  has_secure_password
end
```

advertisement.rb

```
class Advertisement < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
end
```

When creating an advertisement I get an Unknown Attribute user_id on
    @advertisement = current_user.advertisements.create(advertisement_params)

this line. It should call current_user, which is on application_controller.rb

```
def current_user
  @current_user ||= User.find(session[:user_id]) if session[:user_id]
end
```

EDIT: Now if I create and `advertisement` and then list it, I get

```
[#<Advertisement id: 1, created_at: "2016-02-27 00:50:55", updated_at: "2016-02-27 00:50:55", title: "my advert", body: "it belongs to me!", users_id: nil, user_id: 1>
```

Note the `users_id: nil`. I think, while it is filling the `user_id` it's not doing the `belongs_to` thing right. Where is the `users_id: nil` coming from? I'm only concerned because, when I delete a user, I want all their `advertisements` to be deleted as well (and not wasting space on ym database).

Comment: You can try 1. Run and restart your app 2. Check if advertisements table has `user_id`, `title` and `body` columns.

Comment: Do you have `user_id` column in your `advertisements` table in database?

Comment: I have `belongs_to :users` in my `advertisements` table

Comment: @archana I don't. If I add it, what type would it be? I assume it's not a string.

Comment: ID columns are of type integer

Comment: @archana than you very much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like your `advertisements` table has a column named `users_id`, and it should be `user_id`. I would write a migration to change the name of that column.

You can fix this by first generating a migration:

```
 rails g migration rename_advertisements_users_id
```

Then giving the migration these contents:

```
def change
  rename_column :advertisements, :users_id, :user_id
end
```

Then run the migration:

```
rake db:migrate && RAILS_ENV=test rake db:migrate
```

Next time you create a table with a foreign key, do something like this:

```
create_table :pages do |t|
  t.references :book  # not books
  t.text :text
  t.timestamps
end
```

Also, I would **not** fix the old migration. Just write the new one. Here is why: http://illuminatedcomputing.com/posts/2013/03/rules-for-rails-migrations/

Comment: It does. When would this column have been created? Is it important to rails's hierarchy schema?

Comment: Rails wants you to use the singular in some places and the plural in others. Mostly it makes sense, but it takes a little getting used to. Since an advertisement has *one* user, it is `user_id`, not `users_id`. I'll update the answer with how you can change it.

Comment: I deleted the `users_id` column and left `user_id` (sorry, only saw your edit now. I just dropped the users_id one, which was nil), which works. However, in relation to your answer, how do I pass with user owns the `adbertisement` then?

Comment: Your original approach is fine: `current_user.advertisements.build(advertisement_params)`. The ad's `user_id` will be set automatically because you built it as part of that association.

Comment: I'm getting a `undefined method `build' for #<User:0x007fbe82372588>` using the .build method.

Comment: Not `current_user.build` but `current_user.advertisements.build`. It means "in my collection of advertisements, build another one".

Comment: sorry for the misperception. I get a unknown attribute 'user_id' for Advertisement. when I do it the right way, though.

Comment: You said you dropped the `users_id` column. Did you add a `user_id` column in its place?

Comment: seems you were right again. I had both collums before recreating the database, `users_id` and `user_id`, but rails keeps creating `users_id` for some reason. I'll have to look for where this is coming from. Thanks very much_!

Answer (score 0):

This won't work in your advertisement create action:

```
@advertisement = current_user.advertisements.create(advertisement_params)
```

If an ad belongs to a user...user_id should be in the permitted params for advertisement. And then you should pass the current_user.id to Advertisement.new with the other params (one way to do it is via hidden_field in your form).

You shouldn't call .create from inside your create action.

Saying

```
if @advertisement.save
```

Will save object and it will be created. Hope this helps.

Comment: So I would add :user_id to the permitted parameters, and then call `@advertisement = Advertisement.new(advertisement_params)` in `advertisements#create`? Would that assign the advertisement to the current user in the database?

Comment: now I have a column, `users_id: nil` that is always nil. Where does this come from?

Comment: You should definitely *not* send the `user_id` in the parameters hash, unless you want people to create advertisements for other users! But instead of `create`, say `current_user.advertisements.build(....)`. Then it won't save until the next line.

Comment: you can pass user_id as a hidden_field through your form.

Comment: something like <%= f.hidden_field :user_id, value: current_user.id %>

Comment: then simply pass the params to @ad =  Advertisement.new(advertisement_params) and the if ad.save will create the object and assign the user_id for you.

Comment: @karma_police this works, but what about what Paul said?

Comment: @PaulAJungwirth What would `build(...)` take as parameters?

Comment: `build(advertisement_params)`. It is the same as `create`, but it doesn't do a SQL `INSERT` until you say `save`.

Comment: If you are just learning Rails this is a great resource: https://www.railstutorial.org/ . Look for the little "Read Online Free" text.

Comment: Thanks a lot @PaulAJungwirth! You've been a great help!

Comment: @HolyThunder I think Paul's approach is fine. Disagree that it's dangerous to pass user_id as a hidden_field in rails. I could be wrong but I've done it that way many times.

Comment: @karma_police thanks! I'm relatively new to this so I can't judge, but both your approaches seem fine to me. I'm thinking of a way in which a user would fabricate a user_id, but I'm not sure. Thanks for your input either way!

Comment: @HolyThunder you're welcome. Glad you got it working either way.

Comment: @karma_police so am I!